# My website is displaying broken link icons, how can i remove them?

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, icons

as any request for help starts im new to this but ive got some knowledge of html and css and have recently began to understand wordpress. I am working on a new website which i have recreated with wordpress, its still a work in progress as i am still adding content to pages and finally its all coming together, but i find myself confused...there are six images, social media icons for facebook, twitter and google plus that are showing a broken link icon...the link works but ive tested in firefox, safari chrome etc and they all show the link is broken?

plz help http://www.wheretogetawebsite.net/ the site is not complete so plz excuse the empty pages...i just cant seem to figure out why this is happening

thankyou in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

`#twittertop`, `#facebooktop`, and `#googletop` all have an `<img src=`.

These divs already have background images, so you should just remove the `<img src=`.

Otherwise, remove the background-image of these divs and put `wp-content/themes/Where%20To%20Get%20A/` at the beginning of each img src.

Comment: @GaryRobinson Please consider marking this answer as the correct answer, if that is what helped you. :)